# QTabWidget does not work properly in PyQt5

Tags: pyqt5

I need to have several tabs in my window. Two different tabs were added, however if I click second tab, there are still widgets from the first tab (see pictures below). I guess second tab's widgets are just behind, but I'm not sure. Here is my code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout,QPushButton, QTabWidget
import sys

class confWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = "Main window"
        self.width = App.primaryScreen().size().width()/3
        self.height = App.primaryScreen().size().height()/2
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, self.width, self.height)

        tabs = QTabWidget(self)
        tabs.setFixedSize(self.width, self.height)
        tab1 = QWidget()
        tab1.layout = QVBoxLayout(tabs)
        tab1.layout.addWidget(QPushButton("1"))
        tab1.layout.addWidget(QPushButton("2"))
        tabs.addTab(tab1, "TAB1")

        tab2 = QWidget()
        tab2.layout = QVBoxLayout(tabs)
        tab2.layout.addWidget(QPushButton("3"))
        tabs.addTab(tab2, "TAB2")

        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = confWindow()
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Pictures:
[TAB 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPe17.jpg)
[TAB 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWYBM.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tab1.layout = QVBoxLayout(tabs)` will not define a layout for `tab1` but for `tabs`. The fact that the layout is assigned to an attribute of `tab1` will not make it a layout of `tab1`. To set a layout for each of the tabs you would need to do something like this instead:

```
class confWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        tab1 = QWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(tab1)
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton("1"))
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton("2"))
        ...
        tab2 = QWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(tab2)
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton("3"))
        ...
```